# While using Spring Batch, I encounter the SQLTransientConnectionException: Connection reset error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb, mybatis

While using Spring Batch, I encounter the SQLTransientConnectionException: Connection reset error.

The corresponding log is as follows:

```bash
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
### Error querying database. Cause: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=125177903) Connection reset
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
### Cause: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: (conn=125177903) Connection reset
at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectCursor(DefaultSqlSession.java:127)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectCursor(DefaultSqlSession.java:116)
at org.mybatis.spring.batch.MyBatisCursorItemReader.doOpen(MyBatisCursorItemReader.java:69)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
```

"Although the solution is important, I am particularly interested in knowing the cause. Is there anyone who can explain?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *SQLTransientConnectionException: Connection reset* means that the connection to the database is (already) closed while your application is trying to read data from it. This can happen for example after a long time of inactivity. The database connection will be closed either by the JDBC driver or by the connection pool (like Hikari) or by the database engine itself.

You can configure a longer idle time and/or timeout and/or provide an SQL statement to keep-alive/verify the connection periodically.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I agree that there is too much data on the table.